# Apps script to clear an infinite range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I run this code and get an error.
How can I clear such a range `"F7:H"`?

```
  fromSheet.getRange("F7:H").clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fromSheet.getRange(7,6,fromSheet.getLastRow()-6,3).clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: false });
```

try this:

```
fromSheet.getRange("F7:H" + fromSheet.getLastRow()).clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: false });
```

Comment: I get `"F7:H"` as an input from the user

Comment: `getRange(...).filter is not a function` I don't think you can filter a rage, but its values

Comment: Yeah.  I didn't look close enough

Comment: The problem with those type of ranges is that when they are used with getValues() they tend to produce a lot of nulls at the end between lastRow and maxRows.